# I live in one state, work for a company that is headquartered in another, and go to work in a third state. Whose overtime laws apply to me?

Tags: united-states, compensation

I'm located in Virginia (though I'm almost positive that doesn't matter). The contracting company I work for is based in Maryland. I work in a federal building with federal workers in Washington, DC (but I am an outside contractor, and am not a federal employee myself).

Whose overtime and labor laws would apply to me? Would it be only the Federal Government's, DC's and Fed's, or Maryland's and the Fed's? Are there any special circumstances that would change the answer to this question?

I did some googling, and the general consensus was that the laws apply based on where you do the work, not on where the company who employs you is based. That being said, I could see these rules being different for a full-fledged State vs. DC, or for working on a Federal Site.

Edit: I'd like to state that I disagree with this migration from the Workplace Stack Exchange, as this seems to go against the stated goals of this exchange as a place for those with a legal background to interact. That being said, I won't turn my nose up if someone has input and can answer my question. I apologize for what I believe is an invalid post for this exchange.

Comment: Comment rather than an answer as I'm not too familiar with US law, but my understanding is that it's almost always *where* you do the work that counts, rather than where you've come from or where HQ happens to be.

Comment: Ask your employer, but usually, jurisdiction should be stated on the contract. If not, you employer/HR will know.

Comment: @berry120 that applies to what I've seen from Google as well. I just wonder if it would be different due to the federal nature of the work. I know that law application can be a little bit different on federal property, and State law may not always apply (IE I won't pay state sales tax on an item purchased at the Navy Exchange if I go there), so their labor laws may or may not apply. May be just federal laws.

Comment: @Tymoteusz Paul, very very few jobs in the States have written contracts.

Comment: IIRC as a contractor, you could ask your company's contracting officer whose handling the project you're on. Depending on your company's contract, if you're direct charge, the government and your managers would probably be unhappy with you needing to charge overtime.

Comment: @pboss3010 it's certainly rare to get OT, but it happens. We recently had an incident where OT was approved. I spoke to the CT office, and their reply was "You're OT exempt, so work as much as you like, provided you get written approval so that we're paid for it." Which seemed too scummy to be applicable.

Comment: @NegativeFriction That sounds like your job is considered exempt and thus any OT rules do not apply.

Comment: @mKennedy I'd still certainly like to check and confirm that against the relevant laws. It's not exactly unheard of to tell people "You can't do a thing" when they really can, because it would mean that you have to pay out more money. DC explicitly states that anyone caught denying legitimate overtime pay/claiming a false exemption owes 4 times the denied OT wages to the employee.

Comment: @NegativeFriction I understand the desire to check. Someone might be able to help if you include your job title/duties, For example, programming/developer jobs are almost always considered exempt. You do need to get paid a certain wage.